# How to move unique_ptr to raw pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I have a function that is used to allocate a buffer with given size. The buffer will be preprocess/filled some data before return. This preprocess may return false to represent this buffer is not processed right. So I want to apply **RAII** on this buffer to avoid early return without `delete[]` it.

Usually I use `unique_ptr` to help me to auto release the local allocated object. In this case I need to return this allocated object (Owned by `unique_ptr`) and **transfer the ownership to caller**. But the compiler complains that I cannot convert `unique_ptr<T[]>` to `T*` while I `std::move` the `unique_ptr`. It looks like `unique_ptr` can only be moved to another `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointer.

Is any way to transfer the ownership from `unique_ptr` to a `raw pointer`? Or just the `unique_ptr` is not suitable for this case?

```
bool PreProcess(int* v) { /* return nothing wrong? true: false; */ }

bool GetBuffer(int** ppRetBuf, int size)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> buf(new (std::nothrow) int[size]());
    if(PreProcess(buf.get())
    {
        *ppRetBuf = std::move(buf); // Compiler complains:  
                                    // Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'int *'
        return true;
    }
    return false; // No need to manually delete[] failure buffer
}

int main()
{
    int * buf = nullptr;
    GetBuffer(&buf, 100);
}
```

Comment: As far I can see the `std::unique_ptr` doesn't give you any benefit here. Just use a raw pointer in first place then.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yeah... I does not read the description documentation carefully indeed. Maybe I though the Release is like IUnknown::Release() so that I does not check unique_ptr::release further what it is.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the documentation on that website is generally clear and direct, it's a good resource and you might want to bookmark it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How to move unique_ptr to raw pointer?

Well, that's one way of avoiding any benefits of using unique_ptr here.

You *can* use `std::unique_ptr::release()` but then the use of `unique_ptr` is pointless in the first place. Consider returning a `unique_ptr` instead. That way the caller knows that they own the pointer and the array will be freed when they stop using it. Otherwise you'd have to document that the caller must deallocate and how they must do it.

If that's not an option, then there's no use for `unique_ptr` at all unless you are doing something that might throw between constructing the array and returning it and left it out for simplicity.

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` is not pointless in combination with release. You might be dealing with external code that wants raw pointers. Then you can use a `unique_ptr` during construction of these objects. If any exceptions are thrown before you hand them to the external code the object is then still deleted.

Comment: @Aedoro As I said, "there's no use for unique_ptr at all **unless you are doing something that might throw between constructing the array and returning it**"

Answer (score 7):

Since ppRetBuf and buf are two different data types
the compiler gives the error message for that.

In order to do what you want to do you need to
call release on buf

```
*ppRetBuf = buf.release();
```