# Calling overridden function within component of class

Tags: c++, inheritance, components, unique-ptr

I have 4 classes, `Customer`, `PickyCustomer`, `SegmentCustomer`, and `Delivery`.

The `Delivery` class has a component within it called customer, like so:

```
    class Delivery {
      private:
        Customer *customer;

    Delivery(Customer *cust) // constructor
```

each of the `Customer` classes have a method called `getAcceptable()`
that is overrideable and is overridden within `PickyCustomer` and `SegmentCustomer`

From what I've read this is the correct way to call the overridden method from the `Delivery` class. By keeping the `customer` as a pointer it allows `Delivery` to call the child methods that override the base class.

But when trying to use `unique_ptr` I keep getting the error
`no matching function for call to 'Delivery::Delivery(std::unique_ptr<Customer>*)'`

when using the following bit of code to initialize

```
  unique_ptr<Customer> cust1(new Customer("Name", "Home", 1000.0, 25.0, fileProduce));

  shared_ptr<Delivery> cust1Delivery(new Delivery(cust1));
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error, and show how I could fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Explain the ownership semantics, please.  Are you trying to transfer ownership of the customer pointer into `Delivery`?  Or are you trying to have the delivery object simply reference it (as a raw pointer)?  If the former, be aware that a customer may only have a single delivery.  If the latter, just pass `cust1.get()` but be aware that the customer must exist for at least as long as the `shared_ptr` to the Delivery.  Otherwise you can end up with a dangling pointer.  You may want to consider storing the customer as a `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: A `unique_ptr` is not implicitly convertible to a raw pointer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274922/how-to-move-unique-ptr-to-raw-pointer) for how to release a `unique_ptr` to obtain a raw pointer. However this defeats the purposes of having a `unique_ptr` in the first place. What you are doing here might be better accomplished with references.

Comment: @paddy I am trying to have delivery object reference the customer object. Because all I need is a few getMethods and a mutator. I don’t need or really want to change ownership

Comment: Right, so either store a reference instead, or obtain the raw pointer, or make the customer a shared pointer instead and store that.  Provided the lifetime of the Customer exceeds that of the Delivery (at least in terms of the Delivery object _using_ it), you can get away with a reference or raw pointer.  If the lifetime of each object is decoupled, then use a `shared_ptr`.  If the lifetime is decoupled and customer lifetime is centrally managed, you may want to consider storing a `weak_ptr` in Delivery.

Comment: Solved! Thanks @paddy for the help! using ```get()``` worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: @paddy will definitely work on making sure all of the lifetimes are correct! For the most part the lifetime doesn't matter too much. But I'll definitely work on improving this!

Comment: You're welcome.  You got more than you bargained for here, but you must understand that pointer lifetime is very important.  The managed pointer types since C++11 (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr`) all assist with making ownership clearer and reducing the frequency of accidents.  So, when you're converting to a raw pointer it must be a conscious decision.  That is why a conversion is not implicit.  Otherwise you'd end up with people making exactly the same mistakes programmers have been making for decades.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @paddy in the comments with the help! Using the `get()` function worked for me.

The below works for me.

```
unique_ptr<Delivery> cust1Delivery(new Delivery(cust1.get()));
```